# what are the mercurial hgweb.cgi and python matching versions

Tags: python, mercurial

Mercurial version is 1.9.1

```
C:\Inetpub\hgweb>hg version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.9.1)
(see http://mercurial.selenic.com for more information)

Copyright (C) 2005-2011 Matt Mackall and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

and i'm trying to run the file "hgweb.cgi" located at mercurial

tried with python 2.5, 2.7 and 3.2 but i'm still getting the magic number error.

```
C:\Inetpub\hgweb>c:\Python25\python.exe hgweb.cgi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hgweb.cgi", line 15, in <module>
    from mercurial import demandimport; demandimport.enable()
ImportError: Bad magic number in C:\Inetpub\hgweb\mercurial\__init__.pyc

C:\Inetpub\hgweb>c:\Python27\python.exe hgweb.cgi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hgweb.cgi", line 15, in <module>
    from mercurial import demandimport; demandimport.enable()
ImportError: Bad magic number in C:\Inetpub\hgweb\mercurial\__init__.pyc

C:\Inetpub\hgweb>c:\Python32\python.exe hgweb.cgi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hgweb.cgi", line 15, in <module>
    from mercurial import demandimport; demandimport.enable()
ImportError: Bad magic number in C:\Inetpub\hgweb\mercurial\__init__.pyc
```

What version should i use for python?

> Edit #2

I re-copy the Library.zip contents located in mercurial near to hgweb.cgi and the exception is "No module named mercurial". but there's a folder named 'mercurial' and it contains pyo files. (Tried other python version 2.7, 3.2 and error is the same)

details:

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'> Python 2.5.4: C:\Python25\python.exe
Thu Aug 11 23:24:26 2011
A problem occurred in a Python script. Here is the sequence of function calls leading up to the error, in the order they occurred.

 C:\Inetpub\hgweb\hgweb.cgi in ()
   13 import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
   14 
   15 from mercurial import demandimport; demandimport.enable()
   16 from mercurial.hgweb import hgweb, wsgicgi
   17 application = hgweb(config)
mercurial undefined, demandimport undefined
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named mercurial 
      args = ('No module named mercurial',) 
      message = 'No module named mercurial'
```

> ## Edit 3

Installed python 2.6

And the new error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Inetpub\hgweb\hgweb.cgi ", line 17, in <module>
    application = hgweb(config)
  File "mercurial\hgweb\__init__.pyc", line 26, in hgweb
  File "mercurial\hgweb\hgwebdir_mod.pyc", line 62, in __init__
    ||ƒSt|iƒ}|}xæ|oŞ|i|ƒ}   |   o™||id
  File "mercurial\hgweb\hgwebdir_mod.pyc", line 71, in refresh
    |||ƒS|it|ƒ|dd|ƒSWn<tj
  File "mercurial\ui.pyc", line 43, in __init__
    |iƒ|djotiidƒ}n|id|ƒdS(NtsectionstremapsIgnored: %s
  File "mercurial\demandimport.pyc", line 75, in __getattribute__
  File "mercurial\demandimport.pyc", line 47, in _load
    _demandimportQs:"
  File "mercurial\scmutil.pyc", line 164, in <module>

  File "mercurial\scmutil.pyc", line 180, in opener
    (R÷tctx(smercurial\scmutil.pyctbadfn;s(R-(RRŸRØtbad(RRştoptsRRßR((R÷Rsmercurial\scmutil.pycRŸ3s
  File "mercurial\demandimport.pyc", line 75, in __getattribute__
  File "mercurial\demandimport.pyc", line 47, in _load
    _demandimportQs:"
  File "mercurial\util.pyc", line 503, in <module>
  File "mercurial\demandimport.pyc", line 85, in _demandimport
  File "mercurial\windows.pyc", line 21, in <module>
    cCscy|iiƒSWnKtj
  File "mercurial\demandimport.pyc", line 75, in __getattribute__
  File "mercurial\demandimport.pyc", line 47, in _load
    _demandimportQs:"
  File "mercurial\osutil.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "mercurial\osutil.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Might want to mention where you got your Mercurial from, so that others can inspect the package.

Comment: First used the latest mercurial source from "http://selenic.com/repo/hg" but it throws "magic number" error. Then i used the latest tortoiseHg 2.1.2 (it comes with mercurial 1.9.1) but it can not import mercurial. (ps I'm extracting library.zip contents)

Comment: This fixed the problem for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5662125/14731

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to run this under the version of Python that Mercurial is built against. Unfortunately the FAQ doesn't mention what this is and I can't open a .msi on my current system so you will need to check for a "pythonXX.dll" or some such library installed with TortoiseHG and use it with that minor version of Python.